# Ajax.beginform onBegin function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display a dialog before sending the ajax request, but I'm not getting the correct response depending of the clicked button. but I only get two results or the dialog is displayed but the request is sent or it never sends a request.

I don't want to use pure jQuery due to my strong typed view and my controller action which expects a model, so I think this will be another very big problem I'll need to resolve.

this is my layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
    <title>Checador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Estilos.css")">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    @RenderSection("cs", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div class="linea">&nbsp;</div>
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="principal">
        <tr>
            <td id="Cuadro" align="left" valign="middle">
                <span class="slogan">SOME TITLE</span><br />
                <span class="subslogan">BLAH BLAH</span>
            </td>
            <td id="seccion" valign="top" align="right">
                <div class="lineainfo">
                   @using ( Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }) )
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Cerrar Sesion</a>
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" id="Central">
                <div>
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" id="Pie_Pagina" colspan="100%"><span>Abarrotes Monterrey © 2014 Mexico(Es)</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        function desaparece(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#MensajeRegistro").css({ "background-color": "rgb(252, 210, 7)", "visibility": "visible", "font-size": "1.5em", "color": "#121e2d !important" });

            $(".MarcoResultados").hide("slow", function () {

            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#MensajeRegistro").css("visibility", "hidden");
            }, 1550);

        }
        $(".number").keyup(function (event) {
            var valor = $(this).val();
            //var valor2 = valor.charAt(0);

            $(this).val(valor);
        });
        $(".number").keypress(function (event) {
            var valor = $(this).val();

            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {

                event.preventDefault();
            }

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

below is my partial view

```
    @model checa.Models.WrapperCla
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ChecarEntradas";
}
@section cs{
    <style>
        #dialog-confirm {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
}
    <div id="MensajeRegistro">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Checador/_MensajeRegistro.cshtml",Model);}
    </div>
    @using ( Ajax.BeginForm("Buscar", Model.singlemp, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "BusquedaEmpleados", HttpMethod = "Post" }) )
        {
        @Html.Label("Nombres")<input type="text" id="Nombres" name="Nombres" />
        @Html.Label("Apellidos")<input type="text" id="Apellidos" name="Apellidos" />
        @Html.Label("Clave")<input type="text" id="idd" name="idd" class="number" />
        @Html.Label("Departamento")<input type="text" id="Departamento" name="Departamento" />
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
        }
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
    <div id="BusquedaEmpleados" class="ResultadosEmpleados">
       @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Checador/_EmpleadosEncontrados.cshtml",Model.Empleados);}
    </div>
@section Scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Confirmacion() {
        var response = false;
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Cofirmar": function () {
                    
                    noenvio(response);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    
                },
                "Cancelar": function () {
                    response = false;
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    
                    
                }
            }
     });
            return response;
    }

    function noenvio(response) {
        response = false;
        return response;
    }
</script>

}
```

this one is another partial view which displays the query results of the partial view

```
@model checa.Models.WrapperCla

<div class="MarcoResultados">
    @foreach ( var epm in Model.Empleadoslist )
    {
        using ( @Ajax.BeginForm("Checar", epm, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "MensajeRegistro", HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess = "desaparece(data, status, xhr)", OnBegin = "return Confirmacion()" },
            new { Class = "empleadoForm" }) )
        {
            <div class="empleado">
                @{
            String convertido = "";
            if ( epm.Foto != null )
            {
                convertido = System.Convert.ToBase64String(epm.Foto);
            }
            <img class="fempleado" src="data:image;base64,@convertido" width="80" height="80" />
                }
                <label>Empleado:@epm.nombres @epm.apellidos</label>
                <label>Numero Empleado:@epm.idd</label>
                <label>Departamento:@epm.Departamento</label>
                <input type="submit" value="Checar" />
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Does `$("#dialog-confirm").dialog` refer to jQuery UI's Dialog widget? If this is the case, it runs asynchronously and will not stop page execution to wait for a result.

Comment: yes it is, so what is the best approach to this? may be another widget?

Comment: You could try JavaScript's native `confirm` which should halt execution until an option is chosen.